# PHP time values when Daylight Saving Time (DST)

Tags: php, time, dst

I am developing a system to sign up, which should add up all the time someone has been online in my server. I want to take into account also those extra hours that have to be added or subtracted from the total when time changes due to DST.

It is easy to subtract an hour in the third Sunday of March, because I only have to check if the signing time was before 2AM and the sign-out time after 3AM; it is also easy when, in October, someone signs in before 2AM and signs out after 3AM, in that case, I only have to add an hour.

But what about signing in between 2 and 3AM (let's say 2:30) on the last Sunday of October? How would I know if it is the first time it is 2:30, or the second time? In the first case I should add half an hour to the total, whereas in the second case I should leave it as it was before.

Does PHP's time() function give different values when it is 2:30 for the first time than when it is for the second time? I assume it should, as it returns the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch, and it shouldn't be the same for both cases, but I would like to confirm it.

Edit 1:
This is the code to calculate the two cases I mentioned where it was easy enough:

- (timeChangingDates is a function coded by myself, which given the year, it returns an array of length 2. In the first position there will be the last Sunday of March, in which time changes, and in the second position, the last Sunday of October)
- ($startTime and $endTime are DateTime objects in which sign-in and sign-out datetimes are stored)

  ```
  // If sign-in time is before 2AM and sign-out time after 3AM add an hour(October)
  if ((strtotime($startTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')) < strtotime(new DateTime($startTime->format("Y").'-10-'.timeChangingDates($startTime->format("Y"))[1].' 1:59:00')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))) && (strtotime($endTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')) > strtotime(new DateTime($startTime->format("Y").'-10-'.cambiosHorarios($startTime->format("Y"))[1].' 3:00:00')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')))) {
      $totalTime = $totalTime + 60;
  // If sign-in time is before 2AM and sign-out time after 3AM subtract an hour(March)
  } else if ((strtotime($startTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')) < strtotime(new DateTime($startTime->format("Y").'-3-'.timeChangingDates($startTime->format("Y"))[0].' 1:59:00')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))) && (strtotime($endTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')) > strtotime(new DateTime($startTime->format("Y").'-3-'.cambiosHorarios($startTime->format("Y"))[0].' 3:00:00')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')))) {
      $totalTime = $totalTime - 60;
  }
  ```

I haven't tried any way to do the third case mentioned yet, as I cannot simulate time change on Windows. That is why I'd like to know if just using time() would work.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you got any code written? Consider taking the [tour].

Comment: @Script47 Edited to show the code I have done for the moment

Comment: Whatever you're doing there with converting times back and forth between `DateTime` objects and UNIX timestamps and strings is ***insane!*** You can natively `diff` two `DateTime` objects and will get the precise elapsed time, including considerations for DST.

Comment: @deceze still, how would I distinguish both cases? To do a date_diff, I would have to be able to create two DateTime objects, which both represent 2:30AM, but one should be the first time 2:30, and the other, the second, so how could I do that?

Comment: That is indeed ambiguous. "3AM" doesn't mean much when there are two 3AMs that day, and there's no real official disambiguation. It's a problem that's mostly solved in practice by ignoring it. Or rather, if you take a timestamp on a computer "now", it knows the difference. If you want to convert the timestamp to or from a human readable "3AM", the distinction is lost. If it's important, you would have to inspect the particular timezone's DST information and figure out whether the timestamp *is* ambiguous and then ask the user "first or second 3AM?"